# Installing OKI ML 3320 on linux

Tags: linux, printing, printer, cups, dot-matrix-printer

I have an old 9-pin OKI ML 3320 dot-matrix printer and i can't get it to work properly with cups.

When i send any document, the printer prints one line every ~13 seconds, often adding some random gibberish.

using echo "text\nline2\nline3" > /dev/lp0

creates:

```
text
    line2
         line3
```

same when using `cat file.txt > /dev/lp0`.
It looks like the printer makes new line, but doesn't make carriage return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it.

The gibberish was caused by the loose cable, fixing it helped.

The bad line feed behavior was caused by not sending the printer `\r` after `\n`. This printer works in DOS line end mode.

Additional problem was non-ascii characters (ie. language specific letters like ĄĘŃĆ etc. or other alphabets).

To fix all of the above, you need to do the following steps:

- Make sure the LPT cable is tight in both sockets;
- Set proper codepage on the printer;
- Create a script reading input, piping it through `konwert` command*, adding `\r` to end of each line and then writing it to `/dev/lp0`

*konwert - convert to specified charset. http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/konwert/

Available in the repos.